# How to handle the `IllegalArgumentException` in RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using `Retrofit` with `RxJava` for the network calls and `RxBinding` for view operations. In signup screen, upon clicking 'Register' button I'm posting the info to the local server using the `MyApi` service.

**SignupActivity.class**

```
mCompositeSubscription.add(RxView.clicks(mRegisterButton).debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            subscribe(view -> {
              registerUser();
            }, e -> {
              Timber.e(e, "RxView ");
              onRegistrationFailed(e.getMessage());
            }));

private void registerUser() {
 mCompositeSubscription.add(api.registerUser(mEmail,
        mPassword, mConfirmPassword)
        .subscribe(user -> {
          Timber.d("Received user object. Id: " + user.getUserId());
        }, e -> {
          Timber.e(e, "registerUser() ");
          onRegistrationFailed(e.getMessage());
        }));
  }
```

**MyApi.class**

```
 public Observable<User> registerUser(String username, String password, String confirmPassword) {
    return mService.registerUser(username, password, confirmPassword)
        .compose(applySchedulers());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
  }
```

**MyService.class**

```
  @FormUrlEncoded @POST("users/")
  Observable<User> registerUser(@Path("email") String username,
      @Path("password") String password, @Path("password_confirmation") String confirmPassword);
```

The call fails with `IllegalArgumentException` since I'm posting an invalid info.

What's my main issue is, upon `IllegalArgumentException` I thought `RxJava` would execute `registerUser()#ErrorHandler()` since my `registerUser` service call failed with exception but instead it calls `RxView#ErrorHandler()`.

How can I make/force `registerUser()#ErrorHandler()` to take care of the exception occurred during the network call?

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception. It is possible it happens before RxJava is even involved.

Comment: What type is "e"? Maybe it's not general enough to catch all exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, the network call doesn't fail with `IllegalArgumentException` but the request construction itself failed with `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "users/" does not contain {email}".
```

Instead of using **`@Field`** annotation for constructing the POST body , I'd mistakenly used **`@Path`** annotation.

The correct definition:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded @POST("users/")
 Observable<User> registerUser(@Field("email") String username,
      @Field("password") String password, @Field("password_confirmation") String confirmPassword);
```